# Parallel processing in condor

Tags: parallel-processing, distributed-computing, condor

I have a java program that will process 800 images.

I decided to use Condor as a platform for distributed computing, aiming that I can divide those images onto available nodes -> get processed -> combined the results back to me.

Say I have 4 nodes. I want to divide the processing to be 200 images on each node and combine the end result back to me.

I have tried executing it normally by submitting it as java program and stating the requirements = Machine == .. (stating all nodes). But it doesn't seem to work.

How can I divide the processing and execute it in parallel?

Comment: Condor doesn't know enough about your program to be able to automatically decompose your problem for you across nodes.  You'll want to send off 4 condor jobs, each of which operates on 200 images.

Comment: Ya I guess that's the only way as coding a program to automate the task is not in my plan. Thanks anyway for the view !

Answer (score 1):

HTCondor can definitely help you but you might need to do a little bit of work yourself :-)

There are two possible approaches that come to mind: job arrays and DAG applications.

Job arrays: as you can see from example 5 on the HTCondor [Quick Start Guide](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/quick-start.html), you can use the `queue` command to submit more than 1 job. For instance, `queue 800` at the bottom of your job file would submit 800 jobs to your HTCondor pool.

What people do in this case is organize the data to process using a filename convention and exploit that convention in the job file. For instance you could rename your images as `img_0.jpg, img_1.jpg, ... img_799.jpg` (possibly using symlinks rather than renaming the actual files) and then use a job file along these lines:

```
Executable = /path/to/my/script
Arguments = /path/to/data/dir/img_$(Process)
Queue 800
```

When the 800 jobs run, `$(Process)` gets automatically assigned the value of the corresponding process ID (i.e. a integer going from 0 to 799). Which means that your code will pick up the correct image to process.

DAG: Another approach is to organize your processing in a simple [DAG](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v8.2/2_10DAGMan_Applications.html). In this case you could have a pre-processing script (`SCRIPT PRE` entry in your DAG file) organizing your input data (possibly creating symlinks named appropriately). The real job would be just like the example above.